# How do I set a template handler in Rails 3 *not* to use a layout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, templates, handler

I have a rails 3 template handler and would like to configure it not to use the layout. In rails2 we would do a

```
        ::ActionController::Base.exempt_from_layout :extension_name
```

But this method does not exist in Rails 3 any more. I did not find a place within the code where there is an option for a template engine not to run through the layout procedure.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

The option has been [deprecated](http://github.com/rails/rails/commit/72a574b5073b1debd58c954b34c54d3bdee7749f) and then [removed](http://github.com/rails/rails/commit/59e475e3a66fe647ea74f4daf472d82bc9b4535c).

Why do you need it? Unless you create a layout template, Rails shouldn't render the layout.

Comment: Because I am serving the same resource with two different templates. It might be returned as html if the client uses Accept: text/html or xml if the client requests Accept: application/xml or something else if the client requests Accept: something-else/something-else

So I need to be able to have the alayout template (if the server allows html) in addition to the other template engine he is using.